# Stuck on a problem about closed sets and subsets

Tags: general-topology

I am currently working through this problem below in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* and I have no idea where to start. I do not have that much experience with Mathematics at this level so I am finding this problem difficult.

**If $A$ is a closed set that contains every rational number $r \in [0, 1]$, show that $[0, 1]$ $\subset A$**

I have been looking up properties of closed sets in hopes of finding connections that will help me show this is true but I haven't been making much progress.

I am aware that the solution can be found online, but I want to try my best to figure it out on my own. Any hints or assistance that will help guide me towards the answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: consider a point in $[0,1]$ and show that it is a limit point of $A$.  Since $A$ is closed it contains all its limit points.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: A characteristic of a point in a closure of a set is there is a sequence in that set converges to that point. Pick any point in $[0, 1]$, can you find any sequence of rational numbers converging to that point? :)